# ingore duplicate in merge SQL on Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-merge

I have two tables:

src:

| ID | model | accy | delivery_date | ETA | call_off | department | style | duration | plant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | xxyy | MM | 2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-01-17T00:00:00.000Z | paint | pink | 3.3 | dd |
| 123abc | xxyy | MM | 2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | paint | pink | 3.3 | dd |
| 123abc | xxyy | MM | 2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-02-06T00:00:00.000Z | paint | pink | 3.3 | dd |

dest:

| ID | model | accy | delivery_date | ETA | call_off | department | style | duration | plant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | xxyy | MM | 2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-01-17T00:00:00.000Z | paint | pink | 3.3 | dd |

the dest has this row which is the same as the first row in the src table.

whenever I try to merge I get this error:

```
100090 (42P18): Duplicate row detected during DML action
Row Values: ["123abc", "xxyy", "MM", "2022-12-14T00:00:00.000Z", "2022-10-20T00:00:00.000Z", "2023-01-17T00:00:00.000Z", "paint", "pink", 3.3, "dd"]
```

My query:

```
merge into cleaned_delivery dest
using ( 
SELECT distinct
  RECORD_CONTENT:ID::varchar AS ID,
  RECORD_CONTENT:model::varchar AS model,
  RECORD_CONTENT:accy::varchar AS accy,
  RECORD_CONTENT:delivery_date::varchar AS delivery_date,
  RECORD_CONTENT:ETA::varchar AS ETA,
  RECORD_CONTENT:call_off::varchar AS call_off,
  RECORD_CONTENT:department::varchar AS department,
  RECORD_CONTENT:style::varchar AS style, 
  RECORD_CONTENT:duration::float AS duration,    
  RECORD_CONTENT:plant::varchar AS plant

FROM raw_delivery where RECORD_CONTENT:ID

) as src (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant)
on dest.ID = src.ID and dest.model = src.model and dest.accy = src.accy 
when matched
then update set
  dest.delivery_date = src.delivery_date,
  dest.ETA = src.ETA,
  dest.call_off = src.call_off,
  dest.department = src.department,
  dest.style = src.style,
  dest.duration = src.duration
when not matched then insert (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant)
  values (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant);
```

I tried adding this line after the when matched:

```
when matched and (src.delivery_date != dest.delivery_date or src.ETA!= dest.ETA or src.call_off!= dest.call_off)
```

But still the same error. How can I merge these two tables and ignore rows that already exists (duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to allow nondeterministic MERGE by setting [ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#error-on-nondeterministic-merge)

```
ALTER SESSION SET ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE = FALSE;
```

---

Hiding the fact that source provides multiple matching rows is not recommended course of action. A better way is to explicitly state which row should be taken - unique per columns defined on `on dest.ID = src.ID and dest.model = src.model and dest.accy = src.accy` :

```
merge into cleaned_delivery dest
using ( 
SELECT
  RECORD_CONTENT:ID::varchar AS ID,
  RECORD_CONTENT:model::varchar AS model,
  RECORD_CONTENT:accy::varchar AS accy,
  RECORD_CONTENT:delivery_date::varchar AS delivery_date,
  RECORD_CONTENT:ETA::varchar AS ETA,
  RECORD_CONTENT:call_off::varchar AS call_off,
  RECORD_CONTENT:department::varchar AS department,
  RECORD_CONTENT:style::varchar AS style, 
  RECORD_CONTENT:duration::float AS duration,    
  RECORD_CONTENT:plant::varchar AS plant  
FROM raw_delivery 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, model, accy 
                          ORDER BY <here_goes_columns>) = 1  
) AS src
 on dest.ID = src.ID 
and dest.model = src.model 
and dest.accy = src.accy
```

Answer (score 0):

The error show because it seems that there are duplicate rows in the `cleaned_delivery` that match the rows from the `raw_delivery`. If that so, you might need to adjust the condition in the `ON`, so that it doesn't match duplicate rows in the `cleaned_delivery`.

```
MERGE INTO cleaned_delivery dest
USING ( 
 SELECT DISTINCT
 RECORD_CONTENT:ID::varchar AS ID,
 RECORD_CONTENT:model::varchar AS model,
 RECORD_CONTENT:accy::varchar AS accy,
 RECORD_CONTENT:delivery_date::varchar AS delivery_date,
 RECORD_CONTENT:ETA::varchar AS ETA,
 RECORD_CONTENT:call_off::varchar AS call_off,
 RECORD_CONTENT:department::varchar AS department,
 RECORD_CONTENT:style::varchar AS style, 
 RECORD_CONTENT:duration::float AS duration, 
 RECORD_CONTENT:plant::varchar AS plant
 FROM raw_delivery where RECORD_CONTENT:ID
) as src (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant)
ON dest.ID = src.ID AND dest.model = src.model AND dest.accy = src.accy AND dest.delivery_date = src.delivery_date AND dest.ETA = src.ETA AND dest.call_off = src.call_off
WHEN MATCHED AND (src.delivery_date != dest.delivery_date OR src.ETA != dest.ETA OR src.call_off != dest.call_off) THEN 
 UPDATE SET 
 dest.delivery_date = src.delivery_date,
 dest.ETA = src.ETA,
 dest.call_off = src.call_off,
 dest.department = src.department,
 dest.style = src.style,
 dest.duration = src.duration
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant)
 VALUES (ID, model, accy, delivery_date, ETA, call_off, department, style, duration, plant);
```